# change file system from ext3 to ext4 effict on MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql, filesystems, ext4, ext3

I have a situation where MySQL was installed in Linux with a ext3 file system. One table (InnoDB) reached the maximum size allowed for ext3 (2 TB) , insert statement gave "The table 'foo' is full". I have changed the file system from ext3 to ext4 and rebuilt the table again. Yet it has the same issue once its reach 2 TB.

Is there something that I'm missing, that is not allowing the table from extpanding more than 2TB ?

MySQL version is 5.6.19.

innodb_data_file_path variable value is "ibdata1:12M:autoextend"

Comment: Is the file system stored on a GPT partition?

Comment: QUESTIONS : 1) Please run `SELECT @@global.innodb_file_per_table`. What is the value ? 2) What is the filesize of ibdata1 ? 3) Do you have a single table that is 2TB ?

Comment: SELECT @@global.innodb_file_per_table =1
ibdata1 size = 140 MB
Do you have a single table that is 2TB ? yes only one table that reached the 2TB